# How to compute the sum of exponentials of a list of numbers, if we know the summation of the numbers?

Tags: java, exponential

Imagine we know the summation of a list of numbers (that is computed by dynamic programming):

```
a+b+c+d+...
```

How can we compute the sum of exponentials of these numbers without re-iterating over all numbers:

```
Math.exp(a)+Math.exp(b)+Math.exp(c)+...
```

Just a side note, if needed: The numbers are the probabilities of the paths in a lattice structure. The summation of the probabilities of all paths is computed by dynamic programming. However, I need the exponential sum without re-iterating over the lattice structure.

Comment: Which language? Do you have numpy?

Comment: It is in Java. If there is a solution in numpy, I can try to convert to Java. .

Comment: Like "we know the sum of the numbers, but not the numbers themself" ? ^^ explain better

Comment: Do you literally have a list, ie a `List<Integer>` or do you have an array `int[]`?

Comment: The numbers are the probabilities of the paths in a lattice structure. The summation of the probabilities of all paths is computed by dynamic programming. However, I need the exponential sum without re-iterating over the lattice structure.

Comment: Are you asking how to compute the sum of the exponentials of `a, b, c, ...` working from *only the sum* `a+b+c+...` ? Because that is clearly impossible

Comment: Now i'm understanding, for example you have a result  of  `10` and you want to calculate which `Math.exp(nums)` can give that result by summing them, am i right?

Comment: What do you have tried so far? Please show us your code.

Comment: Yes, @khelwood . That's what I need.

Comment: @malaguena Then you're asking for something that is mathematically impossible.

Comment: Ok, then I need to find another solution to compute the sum of exponentials within the dynamic programming. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, @MarcoSalerno.

Comment: Well maybe it isn't mathematically impossible but it needs a lot of computating power, by simply trying every possibility

Comment: @MarcoSalerno So you think that if I tell you "I have 2 numbers that add up to 10", with a lot of computing power, you would be able to tell me what the sum of the exponents is?

Answer (score 1):

Use a stream:

```
int[] numbers;  // given some numbers
double expSum = IntStream.of(numbers).mapToDouble(Math::exp).sum();
```

Comment: The problem is that OP doesn't have the numbers. The desired solution has to magically guess the individual numbers from a given sum...

Comment: This is not possible in dynamic programming. The result is the summation of a list of numbers but without having the numbers separately. All partial solutions are kept in the lattice structure.